# No connection between mongo and laravel using docker

Tags: mongodb, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize laravel project with mongodb but i'm getting

> No suitable servers found (serverselectiontryonce set): [Failed connecting to '127.0.0.1:27107': Connection refused calling inmaster on 27017]

here's my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        volumes:
          - ./data/db:/data/db
        ports:
          - 27017:27017

    web:
        build: .
        volumes:
          - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mongodb/data
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        links:
          - mongodb
        depends_on:
          - mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the mongodb connection string from '127.0.0.1:27107' to 'mongodb:27107' because mongo is running in separate container. Mongodb instance can be reached with linked service name.

Comment: Changed it, didn't work. Same error but changed to mongodb:27107

Comment: From within web container, try to `ping mongodb`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will help you or not but you can try this once. I have also faced the same issue and didn't get any solution from internet. Then i just casually changed this in my .env file and boom it worked for me.

.env ( previousely )

```
# Mongo DB Settings
MONGO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=dev
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=root
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=mongosupersecret
MONGO_DB_AUTHDB=admin
```

.env ( changed to )

```
# Mongo DB Settings
MONGO_DB_HOST=mongo //( put the value whatever written in your docker compose file )
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=dev
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=root
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=mongosupersecret
MONGO_DB_AUTHDB=admin
```

Docker compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    laravel:
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./php/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
            - ./php/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
    database:
        ports:
            - "3307:3307"
    mongo:
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
    mongo-express:
        ports:
            - "8001:8081"
    redis:
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    websocket:
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
    minio:
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
            - "9001:9001"
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```